# Resume application by clicking notification from a service

Tags: android, notifications

I successfully created an activity which starts a service which by turn shows a notification like this

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){

String notificationText = "working"
        myNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .setContentTitle("test")
                .setContentText(notificationText)
                .setTicker("Notification!")
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .build();

//FOLLOWING TECHNIQUE IS DEPRECATED
 /* PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
    myNotification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent); */

        myNotification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
        myNotification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
        notificationManager.notify(1, myNotification);

        return START_STICKY; 
}
```

**I know there are other questions related to this one BUT they all use `setLatestEventInfo` which is deprecated**

And this is what I call from another activity:

```
protected void beginBackgroundSer(){

        intentService = new Intent(this, Service.class);
        intentService.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        this.startService(intentService);

    }
```

So what I'd like is to **resume** the activity whenever I click the notification by non-deprecated methods. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a notification by using the following steps.

1. Create a notification id for the future reference to update the notification by notification manager.

   `// Notification ID to allow for future updates
   private static final int MY_NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;`
2. Create the text elements for the notification.

   ```
   // Notification Text Elements
   private final CharSequence tickerText = "This is a Really, Really, Super Long Notification Message!";
   private final CharSequence contentTitle = "Notification";
   private final CharSequence contentText = "You've Been Notified!";
   ```
3. Define the notification Action elements i.e. when the user clicks on the view in the notification drawer what action happens? We use intents for handling this.

   ```
   // Notification Action Elements
   private Intent mNotificationIntent;
   private PendingIntent mContentIntent;
   ```
4. You can also define sound and vibration for this notification.

   ```
   // Notification Sound and Vibration on Arrival
   private Uri soundURI = Uri
           .parse("android.resource://com.examples.Notification.StatusBarWithCustomView/"
                   + R.raw.alarm_rooster);
   private long[] mVibratePattern = { 0, 200, 200, 300 };
   ```
5. Create the notification using the Notification.Builder class. Do this in your onCreate()

   ```
   mNotificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
           YourActivity.class);
   mContentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0,
           mNotificationIntent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);


               // Build the Notification

               Notification.Builder notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(
                       getApplicationContext())
                   .setTicker(tickerText)
                   .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_warning)
                   .setAutoCancel(true)
                   .setContentIntent(mContentIntent)
                   .setSound(soundURI)
                   .setVibrate(mVibratePattern)
                   .setContent(mContentView);

               // Pass the Notification to the NotificationManager:
               NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
               mNotificationManager.notify(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID,
                       notificationBuilder.build());
   ```

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentations](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setContentIntent(android.app.PendingIntent))

> public NotificationCompat.Builder setContentIntent (PendingIntent intent) - Supply a PendingIntent to send when the notification is clicked. If you do not supply an intent, you can now add PendingIntents to individual views to be launched when clicked by calling RemoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(int,PendingIntent). Be sure to read Notification.contentIntent for how to correctly use this.

So you can use `setContentIntent(PendingIntent intent)` method something like

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
myNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .setContentTitle("test")
            .setContentText(notificationText)
            .setTicker("Notification!")
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent) //added this new line
            .build();

 notificationManager.notify(1, myNotification);
```

Comment: When I click the notification it alerts "We're sorry but the app has been interrupted". Any idea on why?

Comment: I see you accepted an answer but did you get what were you doing wrong? That's important. You need to know why it was saying "We're sorry but the app has been interrupted".